# Low performance in a function?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with a tree hierarchy. It has some tables, but the main ones are two tables, one of them containing the nodes, with a code field like **PK**, and another one with the relationships between nodes, with a ***id*** field like **PK**.

Something like that (the relationships):

```
id(PK) - codefather - codeson - more...
0   -  CODE1       -  CODE11  -
1   -  CODE1       -  CODE12  -
2   -  CODE11      -  CODE112 -
3   -  CODE12      -  CODE121 -
4   -  CODE12      -  CODE122 -
---------------------
```

When I want to see the entire tree I use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.recorrer_principal(
    IN nombretabla character varying,
    IN codigopadre character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    IN _nivel integer DEFAULT 0,
    IN primer_elemento boolean DEFAULT true)
  RETURNS TABLE(codigo character varying, naturaleza integer, ud character varying, resumen character varying, preciomed numeric, nivel integer) AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
tablaconceptos character varying := nombretabla || '_Conceptos';
tablarelacion character varying := nombretabla || '_Relacion';
existe boolean;
nombre_codigo character varying;
codpadre character varying := codigopadre;
c tp_concepto%ROWTYPE;
indice integer;
str_null_case character varying;
BEGIN
IF (codigopadre = '') IS NOT FALSE THEN
    str_null_case := ' IS NULL';    
ELSE
    str_null_case := ' = '||quote_literal(codigopadre);
END IF;
--ROOT ELEMENT
IF primer_elemento IS TRUE THEN
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('SELECT codhijo FROM %I WHERE codpadre %s',tablarelacion,str_null_case) INTO nombre_codigo;
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('SELECT * FROM %I WHERE codigo = %s',tablaconceptos, quote_literal(nombre_codigo)) INTO c;
    codigo := c.codigo;
    nivel := _nivel;
    ud := c.ud;
    naturaleza := c.naturaleza;
    resumen := c.resumen;
    preciomed := c.preciomed;
    RETURN NEXT;
    codpadre := c.codigo;--if it is the first level I change codpadre to that instead the argument of the function
END IF;
--BEGIN TO ITERATE
FOR nombre_codigo in EXECUTE FORMAT ('SELECT codhijo FROM %I WHERE codpadre = %s', tablarelacion, quote_literal(codpadre))
LOOP
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('SELECT * FROM %I WHERE codigo = %s', tablaconceptos, quote_literal(nombre_codigo)) INTO c;
    codigo := nombre_codigo;
    nivel := _nivel+1;
    ud := c.ud;
    naturaleza := c.naturaleza;
    resumen := c.resumen;
    preciomed := c.preciomed;
    RETURN NEXT;
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM %I WHERE codpadre = %s )', tablarelacion , quote_literal(nombre_codigo)) INTO existe;
    --SI QUEDAN MAS HIJOS:  
    IF existe = TRUE THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM recorrer_principal(nombretabla,nombre_codigo,nivel,'false');             
    END IF; 
 END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION public.recorrer_principal(character varying, character varying, integer, boolean)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The function basically runs over the table of relationships, creating a table with the sons of each node. After that, with the sons of each son, and so on recursively.
Well, surprisingly for me, in a table with 12587 nodes, 39084 relationships, the function returns 52117 rows in 02:25 minutes. I think that it is too much time for this task, but maybe is a normal performance. (In this case I'll have to change the function or even the strategy, because always I open my program this tree is created, and it is too much time for wait)

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is relative high overhead related to query start. It is higher when you use dynamic SQL - `EXECUTE` command. Your design doesn't look to be good for performance - so 2min can be ok (maybe not - maybe there can be one more slow query). You should to use some profiler - try to use https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/02/13/plprofiler-getting-a-handy-tool-for-profiling-your-pl-pgsql-code/ or profiler in plpgsql_check https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/07/30/using-plpgsql_check-to-find-compilation-errors-and-profile-functions/

Comment: It looks like the dynamic SQL can be combined into a single dynamic SQL statement, using a recursive CTE. The function recursively calls itself, too. Why?